# foldp and appending a list in Elm result in stack overflow

Tags: elm

I'm trying to make an interactive chart with Elm. My initial approach was to append a state list with signal values and plot a line from that list. However, I can not get this working as appending a list in foldp gives me stack overflow error (see the code).

```
import Random
sig = Random.range 0 100 (every second)
rollLs = foldp (\os s -> os ++ [s]) [] sig 

main = lift asText rollLs

"Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes."
```

Is it intended behaviour? Would anybody advise on a better approach on managing a state which is a list of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have a type issue here. Your function (\os s -> os ++ [s]) cannot be computed and actually the compiler is getting a stack overflow (not the running of your code).

Here is a version that does what you were trying to do with the appropriate type annotations:

```
import Random

sig : Signal Int
sig = Random.range 0 100 (every second)

update : Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
update s os = os ++ [s]

--foldp : (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Signal a -> Signal b

rollLs : Signal [Int]
rollLs = foldp update [] sig 

main = lift asText rollLs
```

When in doubt, add in types and you will usually find the bug.

Cheers!